# Get table with non table column(Created by own names) names through SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables Names as like **TableHead** and **Tableasist**

[image]

From these above two tables I want to get one table result like below:

[image]

I explain result table column conditions in below

Conditions:
Get all records where MICR04 value 122 and above this is first condition

```
     Select * From TableHead where MICR04 >= '122'
```

**Date time**: this column should be get as it is no condition

**Parameter Name**:  I have to change column name as parameter and all values fill like MICR04(header of first table of 2nd header)

**Set Value:**  this value get from Tableasist (2nd Table) of Set Temp value 120.. so should be filled 120 in all rows like below

**Process Value**:  process value means MICR04 column value where we get all rows

**HighLimt**:  This value fixed like 150 (Put as it is 150)

**Deviation:** devation =  (High Limit – Process Value)

**Event:** we can take Event value from first table as usual

These result table unknown columns can add after Event in first table so that I will append these table to gridview. I will hide remaining columns.

Comment: Please provide what you have tried and what problems you are running into

Comment: i don't know how i create non column table value.. i just get all records where MICR04 value 122 or above. after i struck how to move

Comment: my English bad sorry.. that's why i used images for better understanding

Comment: Can this question be reduced to make it easier to understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cross join two tables as follows:

```
Select th.datetime,
       'MICR04' as parameter,
        120 as set_value,
        TH.MICR04 as process_value,
        150 as high_limit,
        150 - th.micr04 as deviation 
        Th.event 
From TableHead th cross join tableasist ta
where th.MICR04 >= '122'
```